# How to reverse mv to file - Unix

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix

I accidentaly ran a find and mv command as per below to move some files with specific extensions to a directory. Unfortunately it was early and I was tired and I didn't put and slash on the end and all the .ext files are gone and I am left with a file called 'file' with no extension.

```
   find /folder -iname "*.zip" -exec mv {} /home/zip \;
```

Question is : How can I reverse or extract my .zip files from this 'file'

I have tried to open with archiver, cat, tail, head and it's just abinary output and archiver can't extract

Note: I am on a Imac

Comment: That command wouldn't do anything but complain about syntax errors. No terminator on the `exec`, no operator for the `"*.zip"`. Well actually it would see `"*.zip"` as a directory to search. But that probably didn't exist.

Comment: @thor Ah.. What would be a better option? Using cp, then confirming the files and then rm? Or is there better syntax for cp to use? Its mainly for housekeeping.

Comment: I can't even figure out what you trying to do, that command is so bizarre.

Comment: @Rhys: If you're executing potentially destructive commands, prepend them with an `echo` first and review what will happen.

Comment: @AlanCurrym I have corrected now.

Comment: Also, `mv -t {} ./file` would only succeed if the earlier `find` predicates selected directories. If you really had `-name "*.zip"` those would be directories with names ending in `.zip`, whichi would be odd enough already. And even if you had those, the effect would be to move the file named `file` into the first `.zip` directory. The rest of the `mv` attempts would fail because `./file` isn't there anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically did this with your find:

```
mv a.zip /home/zip
mv b.zip /home/zip
mv c.zip /home/zip
```

And `/home/zip` wasn't a pre-existing directory. So those are just regular file renames. Each one overwriting the previous. All files except the last are dead. `rm`'ed, effectively.

You should be able to rename `/home/zip` to something more reasonable like `foo.zip` and unzip it to get the last zip file's contents back. The others are going to require more work.

You may also be interested in [this Superuser question about undelete](https://superuser.com/questions/107396/is-there-any-free-undelete-software-for-the-mac)

Comment: What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your command:

```
find /folder -iname "*.zip" -exec mv {} /home/zip \;
```

and if /home/zip is **NOT** a directory, all your zip are gone :( except the last one

Try to quickly unmount your disk, and use external tool like sleuthkit (testdisk) to recover `mv`-ed files

Comment: How to force directory creation to avoid this?

Comment: trailing slash on `/home/zip/` would have done it. Using the `-t` form of `mv` would have done it. `mv -i` would have at least asked before overwriting anything.